# Cell value based on number of digits in another cell

Tags: vendor-prefix

If Cell in column A contains 3 digits then cell in Column B should reflect text as "00" and if cell in column A has 2 digits then Cell in Column B should reflect text as "000"

Comment: post what you have tried so far.

Comment: What cell are you talking about?  Excel?  You need to clearly state your problem and the attempt at trying to resolve that problem, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=3,"00","000")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It Worked.

Comment: Happy to know that it worked. Please mark it as answer and mark it as useful. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed speaking of excel cells, then you should take a look into [nested if statements](https://exceljet.net/formula/nested-if-function-example).

I will leave the rest up to you as you have not yet shown enough proof that you have attempted to solve this problem.